# Is it possible to test the health of a graphic card?

Tags: gpu, lifespan

We know that we can test the remaining lifetime in TBW for SSDs, but is there something similar for GPUs?
Is there a kind of heuristic in order to see the current state of the GPU?
I'm asking this because I'd like to buy a second hand GTX 1080 Ti, so I just want to check its condition once taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it's not possible.**

Like all other persistent digital storage media, SSDs have limited write cycle count. It's natural and predictable. We know that every SSD will run out of write cycles at some point and it's fairly predictable. That's what TBW estimates.

But like any other device, SSDs can also fail due to random failures and TBW doesn't take that into account (TBW estimates memory lifetime only). GPUs suffer only this kind of failures - there are no components that have predictable wear patterns.

GPUs that were used eg. for mining have high failure rates because they operated for prolonged periods of time in conditions that they weren't designed for, usually 24/7 with sub-optimal cooling.